# Is posting your personal information and asking for job in reply to the question allowed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, spam

I noticed some of the answers, where it were not actually answers but was something like

> I can do this job for you. Contact me as example@example.com etc.

Should this be allowed on Stack Exchange? I think If we allowed such answers the site instead of becoming Q&A will become a publicity sites.

In such cases what should be done? Should I downvote the question or flag it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## This is not allowed.

Such answers/questions/comments has to be flagged.